# Eclipse Scout Neon Tooltip text for group box

Tags: tooltip, groupbox, eclipse-scout

I try to put tooltip text on group box :

```
@Order(1000.0)
public class TopBox extends AbstractGroupBox {

  @Override
  public String getTooltipText() {

    return "TEST";
  }
....
```

but It appear on wrong place and it is not clickable.

[image]

(Circled i should be after name : Message from Server)

Is this a bug, or should tooltip ob group box be used differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not manage to reproduce it.

[image: Eclipse Scout GroupBox with Tooltip]

Tested on Windows with Firefox.
Scout RT Version 5.2.0.M5.

Comment: Was maybe this fixed in version 5, because we use version 4?

Comment: I recommend you to update as soon as possible. Remember that Scout Neon is Beta (final release in june).